# How to fetch email from office365 using Node.JS and delegated permissions?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, office365

My aim is to fetch emails from a particular office365 email ID using node.js,delegated permissions.

I was able to fetch the same with application level permissions in Azure AAD and ClientSecretCredential but not able to do the same with delegated permissions.
AccessToken is fetched with delegated permission and ClientSecretCredential but access is denied to fetch email.

So tried to use alternate approach to use InteractiveBrowserCredential and DeviceCodeCredential but in both cases I am not able to fetch accessToken.
Using graph API:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Comment: 1. have you sent the admin consent to YES? 2. can you show code of how you implemented it? maybe a github link 3. The main account, does it have a [Microsoft subscription] (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-365-business-standard-one-month-trial?rtc=2) on it,

Comment: Yes I have admin consent for Mail.Read even though its not required for delegated permission.For code I referred microsoft graph's documentation and chatgpt's created code a, I know not a good thing but I am new to node.js :( .Application Pemissions are working for me but it fetches email of all people in organization which I don't want to do hence want use of delegated permissions. The account doesn't have Azure credits. Link to github gist: https://gist.github.com/shashankvaranasi/07b46436c7e95b189d14dd3edd5b8d84

Answer (score 0):

with the comment you left here is a working example of what you need

https://gist.github.com/samuelowad/5c89dacfe04b27cfb9838d666bb9a10e

https://gist.github.com/samuelowad/e2d122efae3c5c8cbf759e8f6842a07f

ensure you set admin consent to read mail yes

Comment: Thanks for the code but I am getting following error:
statusCode: 403,
  code: 'ErrorAccessDenied',
  requestId: null,
  date: 2023-08-05T16:47:15.356Z,
  body: '{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}',

Does the code work with Delegated Permissions?I do have Graph's Mail.Read with Admin Consent granted.

Comment: As far as I know the 1st code which I had shared in GIST as well as your code works only for Application Permissions, for delegated permissions need to use InteractiveBrowserCredential or DeviceCodeCredential or IMAP OAUTH2. I am getting errors in all these three approaches: not able to fetch access token in interactive or device code while there's a authentication error like mentioned in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/875398/read-outlook-mails-via-imap-using-nodejs-and-oauth

Comment: the code I shared works for delegate permission, I had just recently worked a project using delegate permission and that was a sample of the code PoC, so if you are getting an error:
1. do you have an active subscription running on your Azure email account?
2. did you input the correct details inputted?
3. is the access token and "Graph API called at" logged out?

Comment: The details are correct no doubt about that. The azure account is not paid(it had credits earlier valid for month which are expired now),but inspite of that application permission works but not delegated with same azure.Access token is generated.What do you mean by logged out?

Comment: so if the "credits" is expired already it will not work, you need an active subscription for it to work

Comment: Thanks for your reply again,appreciate your help.So delegated permission requires paid account/credits? Because I am able to fetch mail with applications permissions.

Comment: Here is the permissions I have: https://pasteboard.co/sY7yh5J2mvb0.png Can you tell me what all is needed to be set up in azure, because I think I am lacking something. I did an app registration,got the permissions in the image and created a secret key. Anything else is needed?